# mdframed: how to prevent a box from splitting if the remaining content (or the initial content) is too small?

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, mdframed

### Question

I would like to prevent `mdframed` to split a box too early or too late. By this, I mean that I would like the remaining part of the box to always be greater than a fixed length, given before.

It seems to be impossible with the normal options of `mdframed`.

**Does anyone know how to modify the `mdframed` macros so that it has this feature?**

### Picture and code

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[
innerrightmargin = 0.5cm, 
innertopmargin = 0.5cm, 
innerbottommargin = 0.5cm, 
innerleftmargin = 0.5cm, 
skipbelow = 5mm, 
skipabove = 5mm, 
userdefinedwidth = 5cm, 
splitbottomskip = 5mm, 
splittopskip = 5mm,
backgroundcolor = red,  
roundcorner = 5pt,
align = center]


Vestibulum lectus metus, tincidunt at fermentum non, pellentesque at lorem. Vivamus nisl sem, tempor ac mi et, elementum feugiat justo. Pellentesque tristique consequat molestie. Donec non porttitor risus. Praesent adipiscing elementum tortor, commodo ullamcorper justo consequat eget. Aenean eget nulla enim. Nam purus massa, hendrerit quis faucibus eget, consectetur ac dui. Curabitur ornare non ipsum elementum suscipit. Sed a dignissim ligula, nec vestibulum dui. Fusce sed varius tellus.

Vestibulum lectus metus, tincidunt at fermentum non, pellentesque at lorem. Vivamus nisl sem, tempor ac mi et, elementum feugiat justo.

Vestibulum lectus metus.

\end{mdframed}

This is after the \verb+mdframed+ environment.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This might be problematic with multiple page `mdframed` environments, but in this case, adding `\enlargethispage{4pt}` before `\begin{mdframed}` avoids the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I introduce `\widow` which uses the `\widowpenalty` to prevent a hanging single line (unless the whole paragraph only took a single line).  You insert `\widow` as the last word of the paragraph.  In this way, it doesn't apply to your whole document, but is applied locally to resolve a local problem.

This same approach applies outside of `mdframed`, as well.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newcommand\widow{%
  \widowpenalty=10000

  \widowpenalty=150}
\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[
innerrightmargin = 0.5cm, 
innertopmargin = 0.5cm, 
innerbottommargin = 0.5cm, 
innerleftmargin = 0.5cm, 
skipbelow = 5mm, 
skipabove = 5mm, 
userdefinedwidth = 5cm, 
splitbottomskip = 5mm, 
splittopskip = 5mm,
backgroundcolor = red,  
roundcorner = 5pt,
align = center]


Vestibulum lectus metus, tincidunt at fermentum non, pellentesque at lorem. Vivamus nisl sem, tempor ac mi et, elementum feugiat justo. Pellentesque tristique consequat molestie. Donec non porttitor risus. Praesent adipiscing elementum tortor, commodo ullamcorper justo consequat eget. Aenean eget nulla enim. Nam purus massa, hendrerit quis faucibus eget, consectetur ac dui. Curabitur ornare non ipsum elementum suscipit. Sed a dignissim ligula, nec vestibulum dui. Fusce sed varius tellus.

Vestibulum lectus metus, tincidunt at fermentum non, pellentesque at lorem. Vivamus nisl sem, tempor ac mi et, elementum feugiat justo.

Vestibulum lectus metus.\widow

\end{mdframed}

This is after the \verb+mdframed+ environment.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

To make the answer symmetric, I have a comparable solution for orphans at the beginning of a paragraph, to be applied as `\orphan` at the beginning of a paragraph.

```
\usepackage{needspace}
\newcommand\needlines[1]{\needspace{#1\baselineskip}}
\newcommand\orphan{%
  \needlines{2}%
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does the end of your code useful? I think you forgot to delete it, doesn't you?

Comment: @Colas LOL!  Thanks.  It's how I multi-task, by having several source codes lined up at once.  Fixed.

Comment: I don't understand why you set `\widowpenalty` to different values, `10000` and `15`. Do you prefer using `\widow` of the `needspace` package?

Comment: @Colas The large value, 10000, will apply to the current paragraph.  The blank line that follows in the definition is essentially an indicator to start a new paragraph.  Once in the new paragraph, the value is reset to the default value of 150, so that it doesn't affect any subsequent text.